# ordered character placeholders for string of characters

Tags: formatting, subscripts

I can't really explain using many words besides the title, but here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Just a bit of background, so other people might be able to find this later, this is for a Discrete Mathematics class I'm in (I won't go into much detail about the assignment.) We are contstructing strings of length n that fit some pattern and I wanted a nice way to show strings of length n and their characters at the ordered locations.

I've tried the following but it doesn't look well aligned:

```
$\stackrel{\underline{\hspace{0.2cm}}}{1}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\stackrel{\underline{\hspace{0.2cm}}}{2}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\ldots
\stackrel{\underline{\hspace{0.2cm}}}{n-2}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\stackrel{\underline{R}}{n-1}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\stackrel{\underline{R}}{n}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\stringplace` has an optional argument for the width (default 3em, change it to suit).

If you want the top in math mode, change

```
\text{\makebox[#1]{#2}}
```

into

```
\mathmakebox[#1]{#2}
```

which, however, needs `mathtools` in addition to `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\stringplace}[3][3em]{%
  \frac{\text{\makebox[#1]{#2}}}{\scriptstyle{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\stringplace{}{1}
\;
\stringplace{}{2}
\;
\cdots
\;
\stringplace{}{n-2}
\;
\stringplace{R}{n-1}
\;
\stringplace{R}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mainly chose this one due to the shortness in syntax and it seems easier to add extra stringplaces. I had to use about 8 of these in my homework so shortening the syntax was an important feature.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to make a table.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} p{.1cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} %p{.1cm} 
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} %p{.1cm}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} p{.1cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} p{.1cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
&&&\multirow{2}{*}{$\Large{\dotsb}$}&&&$R$&&$R$\\
\cline{1-1}
\cline{3-3}
%\cdashline{5-5}
\cline{5-5}
\cline{7-7}
\cline{9-9}
1&&2&&$n-2$&&$n-1$&&$n$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]